# How to turn off Samsung Galaxy a3 if the screen doesnt work?

Tags: samsung

How do I turn it off? My screen is not broken it just stopped working and i tried to restart it by pressing the on/off button and volume down-button but it didnt work.

Thanks for you if you can help me!

Answer (score 1):

If you know what `adb` is and how to use it, you can run `adb shell reboot -p`

If not, you can install [the following drivers](http://developer.samsung.com/technical-doc/view.do?v=T000000117#none), and extract the [following zip file](http://forum.xda-developers.com/attachment.php?attachmentid=529113&d=1298854290) anywhere. Once done, [enable USB debugging](http://www.samsung.com/au/support/skp/htg/16385), plug your phone in your computer, and double-click on `adbprompt.bat`. You're going to see the following text in a command prompt:

```
Portable ADB Interface - v0.2 Public BETA
Packaged by Kickface of xda-developers forums

adb
```

Simply type `shell reboot -p`. When done, close the window.

For the sake of simplicity, you can, if you want, remove the battery instead. Generally it doesn't break anything.

Comment: Thank you for your answer! I would remove the battery, but my phone unfortunately has non-removable battery.

Answer (score 1):

<kbd>Volume-Down</kbd>+<kbd>On/Off</kbd> turns off the device **if it is connected to USB charger**. Otherwise it reboots the device.

So just connect it to USB prior to pressing those buttons.

Checked myself on several Samsung A3 (2016, 2017) with unresponsive screens.

Comment: Can confirm this worked.